# Распознование нажатие на UITextView

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

Есть ImagePickerView и TextView. При нажатии на кнопку вместо клавиатуры вылезает ImagePickerView. Возможно ли распознать нажатие на TextView, чтобы 
скрыть ImagePickerView( методы keyboardWillShow, keyboardWillHide не подходят.)

Answer (score 0):

Есть разные способы, например:

1. Повесить UITapGestureRecognizer на TextView
2. Стать делегатом UITextViewDelegate и реализовать функцию func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)